# Why is the result inconsistent?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some python code like here.

```
input()
x=map(int,input().split())
y=map(int,input().split())
z=map(int,input().split())
print(sum(x))
print(sum(y))
print(sum(z))

t=sum(x)-sum(y)
k=sum(y)-sum(z)

print(t)
print(k)
```

The input was

```
4
2 3 6 8
2 6 8
2 8
```

The output was

```
19
16
10
0
0
```

How can `t` and `k` be zero?

Comment: `map()` returns an *iterator*.  You consumed all the items of these iterators the first time you called `sum()` on them, a second `sum()` is adding up zero items.

Answer (score 0):

As map() returns a stateful iterator in Python. Stateful iterators may be only consumed once, after that it's exhausted and yields no values. 
So to reuse it you can just convert the iterable to list and do the operations as below:

```
input()
x = list(map(int,input().split()))
y = list(map(int,input().split()))
z = list(map(int,input().split()))
print(sum(x))
print(sum(y))
print(sum(z))

t = sum(x)-sum(y)
k = sum(y)-sum(z)

print(t)
print(k)
```